# How to choose a vehicle that can accommodate the specified number of employees with OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

How to choose a vehicle that can accommodate the specified number of employees with OptaPlanner?

Employee:

```java
public class Employee {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Transport (Vehicle)

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class Transport {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;
    private Integer capacity;

    @PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Solution

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class Solution {

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Transport> transports;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardMediumSoftLongScore score;

    public Plan(List<Transport> transports, List<Employee> employees) {
        this.transports = transports;
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

Constraint

```java
private Constraint transportCapacity(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.forEach(Transport.class)
                      .filter(transport -> transport.getEmployees().size() >   transport.getCapacity()).penalizeLong("capacity",
                    HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD, transport -> transport.getEmployees().size() - transport.getCapacity());
}
```

Given:

- transports with capacity - 20, 4, 6, 2
- employees - 6

The problem is that the algorithm chooses the transport that comes first and meets the given restrictions.
For example, for solving this problem algorithm chooses transport with capacity 20 instead of 6 which is more optimal.

How to solve this problem correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the algorithm chooses the transport that comes first and meets the given restrictions.

This is how the Construction Heuristic algorithm works. Its goal is to **quickly** find a good enough solution that can be further optimized in the next phase called the Local Search.

Now, if you consider assigning 6 employees to the transport with capacity 6 better than the transport with capacity 20, you have to provide incentives for OptaPlanner to make that improvement.

These incentives are expressed in the form of constraints. In this case you could define a constraint that adds a soft score penalty for the unused capacity on each used transport.

Using the transport of size 20 could result in the score of `0hard/-14soft` whereas using the transport of size 6 would result in `0hard/0soft`, which is better.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! Can you tell me how can i implement it? What should I pay attention to?

Comment: Add a new constraint method to your constraint provider. The new constraint will be very similar to the constraint in the question. Use `filter()` to find transports that have at least one employee but less than the capacity. Then penalize the difference. Make sure penalize a softer score level, e.g. `HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT`. Breaking hard constraints makes the solution infeasible. A 6/20 transport is a feasible solution, it's just not optimal.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my life))) I will add the answer separately so that other users can use

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [yurloc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691152/yurloc) we can add 2 constraints:

- The first constraint is responsible for the maximum number of seats in transport.
- The second constraint is responsible for the optimal placement of employees.

```java
private Constraint transportMaxCapacity(ConstraintFactory factory) {
return factory.forEach(Transport.class)
        .filter(transport -> transport.getEmployees().size() > transport.getCapacity())
        .penalizeLong("max capacity conflict",
                HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD, transport -> transport.getEmployees().size() - transport.getCapacity());
}

private Constraint transportCapacity(ConstraintFactory factory) {
return factory.forEach(Transport.class)
        .filter(transport -> !transport.getEmployees().isEmpty())
        .filter(transport -> transport.getEmployees().size() < transport.getCapacity())
        .penalizeLong("optimal placement conflict",
                HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_SOFT, transport -> transport.getCapacity() - transport.getInspectorList().size());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).